# Tomcat 9.0 login conf

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat

I have a problem with Tomcat login configuration. I copied JavaEE dynamic web app to my new computer and I have some errors with the same conf. When I'm trying to login, server redirects me to j_security_check and in eclipse console I have:

```
paź 06, 2017 5:02:47 PM org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm authenticateSEVERE: Exception performing authenticationjava.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:645)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.authenticate(JDBCRealm.java:317)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:264)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:557)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:500)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:641)
... 19 more
```

My server.xml conf:

```
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
            driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/musician?user=root&amp;password=" 
            roleNameCol="rola" userCredCol="haslo" userNameCol="login" userRoleTable="rola" userTable="konto"/>

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
```

[Mysql Connector add here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq6BA.png)

Comment: Are you using maven or just eclipse?

Comment: Im using just eclipse